# Removing parenthesis from a string in pandas with str.replace

Tags: regex, pandas

I have a list of countries where some have a space and parenthesis after, for example, *"Bolivia (Plurinational State of)"*.

Why doesn't my code below work to only keep *"Bolivia"*?

```
energy['Country'] = energy['Country'].str.replace("Bolivia (Plurinational State of)","Bolivia")
```

Comment: `\(` matches `(` in a regex

Comment: Also: just say `energy['Country'].str.replace(... inplace=True)`. No need to reassign the LHS `energy['Country'] = energy['Country'].str.replace(...)`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`str.replace` uses regex to perform replacements. The parentheses must be escaped to keep them as simple characters:

```
energy['Country'].str.replace("Bolivia \(Plurinational State of\)","Bolivia")
```

You can automate escaping like this:

```
import re
energy['Country'].str.replace(re.escape('Bolivia (Plurinational State of)'),"Bolivia")
```

Comment: This works, however I ended up finding a different way that would take out all parentheses throughout the whole column.

Answer (score 13):

This removed all instances of where there were parentheses with words in them:

```
energy['Country'] = energy['Country'].str.replace(r"\(.*\)","")
```

Comment: With this version you will get trailing white spaces as you don't take them into account before the open bracket.

Answer (score 6):

```
energy['Country'] = energy['Country'].str.replace(r"\s+\(.*\)","")
```

Solution of @python_new_user but solve a white trailing problem mention by @Boud

Answer (score 1):

```
energy['Country'] = (energy['Country'].str.replace(r' \(.*\)','')).str.replace('\d+', '')
```

This will remove contents in parenthesis as well as parenthesis. This will also remove digits in country name.

Answer (score 1):

Using the solution of @AdityaChaturvedi we can also add and extra `\s` before the `\(` to remove the white space before parenthesis. I'm just working with a DataFrame in Pandas also with a list of countries and I'm dealing with this special case.

```
energy['Country'] = (energy['Country'].str.replace(r'\s\(.*\)','')).str.replace('\d+', '')
```