# How to strip last three characters from a column in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas dataframe like this:

```
         Country  Ranking
0     Greece[e]      100
1      China[e]      200
2     Singapore      300
3  Australia[e]      400
4        Zambia      500
5        France      600
6     Canada[e]      700
```

I like to remove any '[e]' under 'Country' column of the DF, to have this:

```
      Country  Ranking
0     Greece      100
1      China      200
2  Singapore      300
3  Australia      400
4     Zambia      500
5     France      600
6     Canada      700
```

When I use:

```
df.Country = df.Country.str.strip('[e]')
```

I get the '[e]' is removed including the last 'e' of country's name (e.g. Singapore, Greece, France).

```
         Country  Ranking
0      Greec      100
1      China      200
2   Singapor      300
3  Australia      400
4     Zambia      500
5      Franc      600
6     Canada      700
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing parenthesis from a string in pandas with str.replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40836423/removing-parenthesis-from-a-string-in-pandas-with-str-replace)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### [`.str.replace()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
df["Country"] = df["Country"].str.replace(r"\[e\]$", "")
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
     Country  Ranking
0     Greece      100
1      China      200
2  Singapore      300
3  Australia      400
4     Zambia      500
5     France      600
6     Canada      700
```